# React apps Localhost broken after installing bootstrap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, localhost

Despite the numerous problems involving localhost 'refuse to connect' error I believe this is unique as it arises only after installing bootstrap. It took me a while to isolate this as the problem. I can create an app using:

npx create-react-app name

initalise it with:

npm start (in correct directory)

All works as should. I can continue to use like this no problem. But as soon as bootstrap is installed for this project with:

npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap

the dreaded local host 'refuse to connect' error appears and this permenantly breaks the project, curiously even when bootstrap is uninstalled in this project. All the troubleshooting for localhost refuse to connect issue has been thus far unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your error logs or console output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
$npx create-react-app name

$cd name 

npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap

npm start
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked a treat. Curious as to why this occured, whilst this fixes my problem its a bit concerning that you have to instal a particular library at the start. Would be good to know that if you changed your mind half way through a project, or forgot to install it wouldn't be jepordised...